# Using a ternary operator to output a string

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Why does this

```
var marketName = (controller.state.operation.code === 'copy')
    ? controller.state.market.targetName
    : controller.state.market.name;

$('dd.preview-step1').html(
    'Market = <i>' 
    + marketName 
    + '</i><br />Source = <i>'
    + controller.state.source.name 
    + '</i><br />Target = <i>'
    + controller.state.target.name
    +'</i>'
);
```

output this:

> Market = blabla 
>   Source = blabla 
>   Target = blabla

While this

```
$('dd.preview-step1').html(
    'Market = <i>'
    + (controller.state.operation.code === 'copy') 
        ? controller.state.market.targetName
        : controller.state.market.name
    + '</i><br />Source = <i>'
    + controller.state.source.name
    + '</i><br />Target = <i>'
    + controller.state.target.name 
    + '</i>'
);
```

only outputs this:

> Market = blabla

I don't get why the rest of the string after the inline ternary operator is not printed.

Thanks for help.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it does not know that the `+` is not part of it. Use () around the ternary part so the order of operations does what you want.

```
$('dd.preview-step1').html('Market = <i>'+ 
    ((controller.state.operation.code === 'copy') ? controller.state.market.targetName : controller.state.market.name)
     +'</i><br />Source = <i>'+ controller.state.source.name +'</i><br />Target = <i>'+ controller.state.target.name +'</i>');
```

See the extra `(` and `)` I added at the beginning and end of the second line above.